# how to declare custom.d.ts to my customized stylecomponent?

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

my component code is:

```
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const GlobalButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: ${(props) => (props["bc"] ? props["bc"] : "#2962ff;")};
  width: ${(props) => (props["width"] ? props["width"] + "px;" : "250px;")};
  height: ${(props) => (props["height"] ? props["height"] + "px;" : "35px;")};
  margin-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

usage

```
<GlobalButton width={340} onPress={handleConfirm}>
  <GradientButton>
    <GlobalText color="#FFFF" fontSize={18} fw={340}>
      Confirmar
    </GlobalText>
  </GradientButton>
</GlobalButton>
```

typescript complain about my props color, fontSize and fw, how correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define type for your `GlobalButton`:

```
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const GlobalButton = styled.TouchableOpacity< color?: string; fontSize?: number; fw?: number >`
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: ${(props) => (props["bc"] ? props["bc"] : "#2962ff;")};
  width: ${(props) => (props["width"] ? props["width"] + "px;" : "250px;")};
  height: ${(props) => (props["height"] ? props["height"] + "px;" : "35px;")};
  margin-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

many thanks, works fine now!

```
type GlobalTextProps = {
  fontSize?: number;
  color?: string;
  fw?: string;
  marginTop?: number;
  marginLeft?: number;
};

export const GlobalText = styled.Text<GlobalTextProps>`
```